# BGE Navmesh Detection Script

Tags: scripting, game-engine

[image]
I want the red cube to detect near navmeshes. Is i possible? I need it to change navmesh by its name after reaching the intersection so car will turn on intersections on random.

Comment: Why do you have different navigation meshes? (The steering will not be able to find a path to locations on the other navigation mesh). Your question looks like you want the do something else (changing the target location)

Comment: I actually need to to change between meshes. The idea is to have different mesh for every lane on the street so the car will follow only his own lane one the right side of the road. Unless there is other way to make car follow only right side of the navmesh that i dont know? Do you know some way to do it? 
Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: I understand. It is an interesting argument. I do not think the build-in steering supports one-way sections.